# A fantomatic treasure goblin is following me

Tags: diablo-iii

I played my Daemon hunter yesterday (level 38), and since Act IV (High Heavens), a fantomatic treasure goblin is following me everywhere like a companion. I have absolutely no idea from where he comes from. Here are some screenshots:

**In Act IV**

[image: In the act IV]

**In Act I** (even after killing Diablo and restarting a game he's still here)

[image: In the act I]

Maybe it's one of my skills?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is the effect of a puzzle ring.

> Summon a treasure goblin who picks up normal-quality items for you. After picking up 12–16 items, he drops a rare item with a chance for a legendary.

Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/puzzle-ring

Comment: Thanks to both of you ! I wondered why I drop more legendary items :)

Comment: @Chippies As of patch 2.3.0 (which adds the Kanai's Cube) there is also another use of the puzzle ring. I don't want to spoil the fun, but it's quite useful.

Comment: @Asunez that is true, it's certainly a better use than actually wearing it :P But not really related to the question, I think.

Answer (score 7):

Are you wearing a [Puzzle Ring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/puzzle-ring)?

This gives you a goblin pet who collects white items for a rare item and a chance at a legendary.

Answer (score -2):

It collects low quality weapons you find from weapon racks. It will collect up to 12-16 at a time.

It has a chance to drop a rare item, sometimes a legendary.

Comment: This just seems to be a harder to read version of the [accepted answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/160426/51171).