# Why did I get surrounded by so many treasure goblins?

Tags: diablo-iii

*I think I'm starting to ask [too many stupid questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160425/a-fantomatic-treasure-goblin-is-following-me) about treasure goblins.*

I was slashing some mobs in the first level of a Nephalem Rift with a friend (it was like 3 minutes after we started), and suddenly:

[image: Screenshot showing multiple goblin portals]

Yes : 9 treasure goblins at the same place.

Is this normal?

Comment: It was even better with the double goblin community buff, during the last major patch :)

Comment: My screen was full of gold coins, I can't imagine during this buff !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't common, but it can definitely happen. Every time you spawn into a floor of a Nephalam Rift, it randomly chooses which enemies will spawn on that floor. One of the groups of enemies is a lot of treasure goblins all at once. It's definitely one of the rarer enemy groups, but is fun when it happens. :)

Comment: I wondered how this could be redone :)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely normal. I think these probably occur in one of 20 to 30 games. They will only occur inside of a rift.

If you can kill a significant amount of them then it is usually a lot of fun. If you are playing above your level it can be discouraging to only kill one or two.

From what I have seen there does not seem to be a pattern to these groups forming with regards to people, levels, the type of game, etc.

Screenshot:

[image]

And video just for fun, this was in a T13 rift:

[image: video]